# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages Dingo/api does not install on laravel v5.5.24

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, dingo-api

I want install `Dingo` package on my project and when I do

```
composer require dingo/api:"2.0.0-alpha1"
```

I have a [lot of errors](https://gist.github.com/informagenie/a9e61dc9ddda717843ede2ba6469b797)

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to update instand of require

I added

```
"require": {
   "dingo/api": "2.0.0-alpha1"
}
```

Before to update

```
composer update
```

And now all is fine !